# ViewCell repeated many times in Listview Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have

1. Test.xaml

   ```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="myCarts" HasUnevenRows="true">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label TextColor="#848484" Text="11" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
   ```
2. Test.xaml.cs

   ```
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var cartUserInfo = Preferences.Get("CartUser", "defaultcart");

        myCarts.ItemsSource = cartUserInfo;
    }
   ```

I checked the data in `cartUserInfo` Preferences only 1 line of data. Why does it repeat again in the UI?

[image]

How does it display correctly. Thank you

Comment: `cartUserInfo` must contain more than one element.  How are you checking this?

Comment: I'm really stupid.
I added: var getcart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(cartUserInfo);
myCart.ItemsSource = getcart; --> It solved the problem, Thank Jason